# How to choose Kafka transaction id for several applications, hosted in Kubernetes?

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a classic microservice architecture. So, there are differ applications. Each application may have `1..N` instances. The system is deployed to `Kubernetes.` So, we have many differ `PODs`, which can start and stop in any time.

I want to implement [read-process-write](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/) pattern, so I need Kafka transactions.

To configure transactions, I need to set some `transaction id` for each Kafka producer. (Actually, I need `transaction-id-prefix`, because of I use Spring for my applications, and it has such `API`). These `IDs` have to be the same, after application is restarted.

So, how to choose Kafka transaction id for several applications, hosted in Kubernetes?

Comment: I am assuming you need some sort of Atomic id spanning across all producers ? Have you considered using a simple DB sequence in that case which is shared by all producers in your eco system.

Comment: @fatcook nope, `transaction id` is not a DB sequence. Let's consider a example. We have 2 PODs, each pod has own copy of application instance. So, first application has `transaction id == 1`, second one has `transaction id == 2`. Then first POD is down (for example, we deploy new version of application). When first POD start again, it has to get `transaction id == 1`, not `transaction id == 3`

Comment: Then this is more of an application id ? And do you want to have same or different ids for multiple instances of your same application ? Either case this can be also be achieved by using some sort of health check endpoint framework , where you check isAlive on the pod , if Pod is alive then you cannot assign this application id to new pod , otherwise you can..

Comment: @fatcook yea, it is a sort of application id, which is unique for each instance of application. But we need, that this application id is taken from some constant pool of  free IDs. For example, we have `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` application ids. First POD takes `1`, Second one takes `2`. When First POD is die, we need return `1` to pool of IDs. Thank you for health check endpoint idea, it may helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the consumer starts the transaction (read-process-write) then the transaction id prefix must be the same for all instances of the same app (so that zombie fencing works correctly after a rebalance). The actual transaction id used is `<prefix><group>.<topic>.<partition>`.

If you have multiple apps, they should have unique prefixes (although if they consume from different topics, they will be unique anyway).

For producer-only transactions, the prefix must be unique in each instance (to prevent kafka fencing the producers).

**EDIT**

Note that [KIP-447](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-447%3A+Producer+scalability+for+exactly+once+semantics) changed all this; it is no longer necessary (when using `EOSMode.V2` aka `BETA`) to keep the tranactional id the same - consumer metadata is used for fencing instead.

Comment: I have one topic, one consumer group, P partitions, N instances of Application. Each instance of Application has M consumers (for example, 4 consumers in 4 threads). 

So, am i right, that I need unique prefix for each instance? Also, this prefix has to be the same after instance restart?

Comment: No, as I said, if you are using read-process-write, you MUST use the same prefix for ALL instances and, yes, it MUST be the same after each restart. If one of the instances go down kafka will rebalance and the new consumers for those partitions must use the same `transactional.id` that was used by the dead instance.

Comment: oh, It seems, that I can use just some `"string"`. Thank you!

Comment: In case of producer-only, does the prefix need to be the same after restart?

Comment: Don't add follow-up questions in comments; ask a new question and refer to this one if necessary.