# TransactionId prefix for producer-only and read-process-write - ProducerFencedException

Tags: spring-kafka

Background: We have been getting ProducerFencedException in our producer-only transactions, and want to introduce uniqueness to our prefix to prevent this issue.

In this discussion, Gary mentions that in the case of read-process-write, the prefix must be the same in all instances and after each restart.
[How to choose Kafka transaction id for several applications, hosted in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57179169/how-to-choose-kafka-transaction-id-for-several-applications-hosted-in-kubernete)

While digging into this issue, I came to the realisation that we are sharing the same prefixId for both producer-only and read-process-write.

In our TopicPublisher class wrapping kafkaTemplate, we already have a publish() and publishInTransaction() methods for read-process-write and producer-only use cases respectively.

I am thinking to have 2 sets of kafkaTemplates/TransactionManagers/ProducerFactories, one with a fixed prefixId to be used by the publish() method and one with a unique prefix to be used in publishInTransaction().

My question is:

- Does the prefix for producer-only need to be the same after a pod is restarted. Can we just append some uuid or k8s podId? Someone mentioned there may be delays with aborting transactions.
- Is there a clean way to detect if the TopicPublisher is being called from a KafkaListener, so we can have just 1 publish method that uses the correct kafkaTemplate as needed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no issue using the same `transactionIdPrefix`, at least with recent versions.

The factory gets a txIdPrefix.

For read-process-write, we create (and cache) a producer with transactionalId:

```
    private String zombieFenceTxIdSuffix(String topic, int partition) {
        return this.consumerGroupId + "." + topic + "." + partition;
    }
```

which is suffixed onto the prefix.

For producer only-transactions, we create (and cache) a producer with the prefix and simple numeric suffix.

In the upcoming 2.3 release, there is also an option to assign a producer to a thread so the same thread always uses the same transactional.id.

1. I believe it needs to be the same, unless you don't mind waiting for `transaction.timeout.ms` (default 1 minute).

> The maximum amount of time in ms that the transaction coordinator will wait for a transaction status update from the producer before proactively aborting the ongoing transaction.If this value is larger than the transaction.max.timeout.ms setting in the broker, the request will fail with a InvalidTransactionTimeout error.

2. This is what we do in `spring-integration-kafka`

```java
if (this.transactional
        && TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(this.kafkaTemplate.getProducerFactory()) == null) {
    sendFuture = this.kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(t -> {
        return t.send(producerRecord);
    });
}
else {
    sendFuture = this.kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
}
```

You can also use `String suffix = TransactionSupport.getTransactionIdSuffix();` which is what the factory uses when it is asked for producer - if null, you are not running on a transactional consumer thread.

Comment: "Actually, there is no issue using the same transactionIdPrefix, at least with recent versions."

We're getting the ProducerFencedException in producer-only transactions with v 2.2.7.RELEASE. Any particular release were this was addressed?

Comment: "For producer only-transactions, we create (and cache) a producer with the prefix and simple numeric suffix." - won't this result in producers in different pods using the same txId?

Comment: Ah; yes; you will need a unique id in each pod for producer-only; so, yes, for that use case, you need 2 producer factories and templates.

Comment: What's the common practice in this case in kubernetes? Pod id/name? Seems like there's no guarantee that podid is the same after restart

Comment: I don't know; I guess you could do something with an ephemeral zookeeper node and have each instance check out an available slot. when a pod dies, its slot becomes available for reuse.

Comment: what happens while waiting for transaction.timeout.ms? Are we unable to publish or consume other messages in the same topic/partition?

The new pod will have a different txId

Comment: That would be my guess, but I really don't know; I'd only be speculating. Why don't you just test it to see what happens?